# how to get woe (weight of evidence) values of all variables and how to apply logistic regression model in r?

Tags: r, vector, logistic-regression

I have categorical variables:

`Y = 0 or 1
X = X1; X2
Z = Z1; Z2; Z3; Z4
V = V1; V2; V3; V4`

How I can get woe for all variables and how to apply logistic regression?

First of all, I don't understand how to get woe vector which will be used for logistic regression model.
For example, I use woe()

`woe(Data=MyData,"X",FALSE,"Y",10,Bad=1,Good=0)`

I get

`BIN   BAD GOOD TOTAL  BAD% GOOD% TOTAL%   WOE    IV BAD_SPLIT
X1   0 33117 3867 36984 0.798  0.38  0.716 -74.2 0.310     0.895
X2   1  8370 6300 14670 0.202  0.62  0.284 112.1 0.469     0.571
  GOOD_SPLIT
X1      0.105
X2      0.429`

But woe is only given to one variable.

Answer (score 0):

To get weight of evidence for all the variables you have to replace the "X" in the below code to that variable for which you want to find weight of evidence.

`woe(Data=MyData,"X",FALSE,"Y",10,Bad=1,Good=0)`

To learn to use woe in logistic regression you can [use this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189568/replacing-variables-by-woe-weight-of-evidence-in-logistic-regression)

Comment: So I get woe values -74.2 and 112.1. How should I change data to woe values? For example I have X=1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0 (here 1=X1, 0=X2). After the replacement X should look like this? X=-74.2, 112.1, 112.1, -74.2, 112.1, -74.2, -74.2, 112.1 ? And X should be numeric vector?

Comment: yes you can do it, or you can use the original variables also as IV is more than 0.2